# Redirect to https not working with www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-redirect

I have a domain called `example.com`.

I want to redirect always to `https://www.example.com` (`https` AND `www`).

Means: I need to redirect

```
https://example.com

http://www.example.com

http://example.com
```

to

```
https://www.example.com
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^web/ /web%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

This is workin for:

```
https://example.com

http://example.com
```

but it's NOT working for:

```
http://www.example.com
```

I'm working on this already the whole day (it's 4 p.m. here) but without success.

Why that? Who can give me a hint? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The rule you are using only only redirects non-www domain to www without checking https header.

you can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on

#http to https with www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]
#other rules
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule !^web/ /web%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

This will redirect both `http` or `non-www` to `https://www`

Clear your browser cache before testing this.